# Javascript - cloning, appending and wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some piece of javascripc code:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.year-dropdown').find('.date, .time, .details').not('.clone').addClass('clone').clone().wrap("<div class='new'></div>").parent().appendTo('#all-events');
```

What this does: This code selects ".date, .time, .details" classes, from particular div, clones them, then add class .clone, to prevent from cloning again.
Next, this code wraps selectd classes to , and lastly, prepend to #all-events.

This code works well, there is just one problem:

all classes are added to new div with class .new.

So this looks like this

```
<div class="new">
  <p class="date clone></p>
</div>
<div class="new">
  <p class="time clone></p>
</div>
<div class="new">
  <p class="details clone></p>
</div>
```

And all i want is to close those classes in one div with class of new:

```
<div class="new">
  <p class="date clone></p>
  <p class="time clone></p>
  <p class="details clone></p>
</div>
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks for advice.

PS : output of curren code, from some answer.
[image]

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First append the `.new` div to `#all-events` and than append the cloned elements to the appended `.new` div
Try:

```
$("<div class='new'></div>").appendTo('#all-events');
     $(this).parent().siblings().find('.year-dropdown').find('.date, .time, .details').not('.clone').addClass('clone').clone().appendTo('.new');
```

or sd @billyonecan suggested use `wrapAll()`

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.year-dropdown').find('.date, .time, .details').not('.clone').addClass('clone').clone().wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>").parent().appendTo('#all-events');
```

Split in groups of 4

```
var items = $(this).parent().siblings().find('.year-dropdown').find('.date, .time, .details').not('.clone').addClass('clone').clone();

var final = '<div class="new">';
$(items).each(function(i,v){
   final+=v;
 if (i%4 == 0 ) {
    final+='</div><div class="new">'
 }
});
final+='</div>';
$(final).appendTo('#all-events');
```

Comment: Code dumps are not useful answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Comment: @madalin ivascu -Great, but i have another question, how can i add every 4th element do new .new class ? Now i have a lot of classes in one <div class="one"> - and i want: if 4 classes are cloned, put them on <div class="new">, but element 5 and later shuld be in new <div class="new"> div, and so on...

Comment: you will need a each loop to loop and add the new class after the 4th element in the object

Comment: final.appendTo('#all-events'); causes errors, as chrome console says:Uncaught TypeError: final.appendTo is not a function